# How to obtain the mac address of a client

Tags: http, networking

How can i obtain the mac address of a client sending a request to my webapp? 
I made some research but it looks like it can only be done when client and server are in the same lan.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the client's MAC address? If the client does not send its MAC to the server as part of the HTTP request, the server will have to use ARP to query the MAC, but ARP only works on the same network.

Comment: I do not need it to be honest. I was just curiosity. So does it get sent or not over http?

Comment: Socket code does not need to care about MAC addresses, that is a detail of the underlying networking system outside of the application layer.  And no, the MAC is not sent over HTTP (unless explicitly sent as a custom HTTP header or URL/POST parameter).

Comment: You don't need the MAC address, and it doesn't have any practical use or indeed meaning outside the LAN in which it operates. People think they can use them as unique machine identifiers, but they can't. For one thing, MAC addresses can be changed by the user.

Comment: Therefore, since the mac does not exit the LAN (as it does not travel over http), does that mean the ISP cannot tell who in the LAN requested a certain website? Does it look like all the requests come from that router without further details capable of identifying the actual original computer that sended the request in the first place?